# How do I get the spectrum of 1D and 2D spatial filters used in images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, signal-processing

I would like to know how to obtain the spectrum of a spatial 1 dimensional and 2 dimensional sharpening filter in image processing.

The sharpening filters are:

```
[-1, 3, -1];
[-1, -1, -1; -1, 8, -1; -1, -1, -1];
```

In MATLAB, what should I do to get the spectrum of the filters, or how do I get the frequency components of these filters?

Answer (score 8):

You can use Luis Mendo's post to determine the spectrum of your filter right away.  Use either [`freqz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html) for a 1D filter, or [`freqz2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz2.html) for a 2D filter.  Note that the plot using `freqz` and `freqz2` are in terms of normalized frequency that spans between `[-1,1]`.

However, I'd like to write this post to compliment Luis Mendo's and show you **how** the spectrum is derived.

---

Let's start with your first filter:

```
h1 = [-1,3,-1];
```

If you recall, the 1D [Discrete-Time Fourier Transform (DTFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) is defined as:

[image]

---

## Aside: Why the DTFT and not the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT)?

Take special care that this is **different** from the [Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).  The difference between them is that the DTFT is the traditional Fourier Transform applied to a discrete signal.  From the continuous viewpoint, we apply the normal Fourier Transform where the spectrum is continuous in terms of frequency.  It is essentially the same thing here for a discrete signal, but the transform is applied to a discrete signal.  The output is also continuous in frequency, with the additional constraint that the spectrum is `2*pi` periodic.  For the DFT, it is essentially a **sampled** version of the DTFT **in frequency domain**.  Therefore, the core difference between them both is that in the frequency domain, one is continuous while the other is a sampled version of the continuous counterpart.  The reason why we need to sample the DTFT is so that you can actually store the spectra on computers and let programs process the spectra (i.e. MATLAB).

Your question asked to determine what the spectrum is, and in terms of a theoretical perspective, I will present the DTFT to you.  When we actually **plot** the spectra, we are actually **sampling** the DTFT anyway, so when we see the spectra, you would be visualizing the DFT (more or less!).

A very good explanation about the differences between them both can be found on DSP StackExchange: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16586/difference-between-discrete-time-fourier-transform-and-discrete-fourier-transfor

---

## Back to your question

For the definition of the DTFT, `h[k]` is a 1D signal, and `omega` is the angular frequency defined in radians.  Therefore, you can consider your filter to be this 1D signal and when you filter in the spatial domain, it is the same as taking this signal, transforming it into the frequency domain and performing multiplication with another input signal in the frequency domain.

Therefore, if we consider that your filter is symmetric, the value of 3 is defined as the **centre** point.  As such, you can think of `h[k]` as:

```
h = [-1    3  -1]
      ^    ^   ^
k =   -1   0   1
```

Therefore, the frequency domain representation is simply a weighted sum of the filter coefficients with complex exponential terms.  Substituting `h[k]` into the Fourier Transform formula, we get:

[image]

If you recall [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), we have:

[image]

Similarly:

[image]

If we add the two equations together, we can rearrange and solve for `cos(x)`:

[image]

Going back to our transform of our 1D filter, we can do some factoring:

[image]

Note that the domain is between `[-pi,pi]`, as the 1D Fourier Transform is `2*pi` symmetric.  As such, if you want to show the spectrum, simply plot using the above domain and use the equation that I just created, plotting the **absolute** value, as the magnitude of the spectrum is always positive:

```
w = linspace(-pi,pi);
h = abs(3 - 2*cos(w));
plot(w,h);
title('Magnitude of 1D spectrum');
axis([-pi, pi, 0, 5]);
```

[`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) generates a linearly increasing array from `-pi` to `pi` with 100 points in between the ranges.  You can override this behaviour by specifying a third parameter that manually tells `linspace` how many points you want to generate, but the default is 100 if you omit this parameter.

Note that I've made the `y`-axis extend from 0 so you can see where the curve starts at and it going up to 5 as this is the maximum value that is ever possible for `h`.  This is what we get:

[image]

Indeed the above spectrum certainly looks like a high-pass filter, and because the magnitude at the DC frequency (`w = 0`) is 1, you are essentially adding the original signal on top of the high-pass filtering results, which thus "sharpens" your signal.

---

You can do the same process with the 2D case, though it will be a bit more involved.  In the 2D case, the Discrete-Time Fourier Transform is defined to be:

[image]

We have two independent variables to consider, and we will have 2D spatial frequencies.  `w1` and `k1` will operate along the **rows** of the 2D signal and `w2` and `k2` will operate along the **columns** of the 2D signal.

Given your mask:

```
h2 = [-1 -1 -1; -1 8 -1; -1 -1 -1]
```

As the shape of `h2` is symmetric, the value of 8 will be location `(w1,w2) = (0,0)`.  Therefore, when we calculate the spectrum with the above equation, we get:

[image]

I'll save you the trouble with the simplification, but doing some rearranging and making use of Euler's formula, we get:

[image]

Note that:

[image]

I used the above property to make the simplifications possible.  For the 2D case, we will define a [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) of coordinates that both range between `[-pi,pi]` for both dimensions, and we will plot this on a surface plot with [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html).  Remember to take the **absolute** value of the filter to show the magnitude:

```
[w1,w2] = meshgrid(linspace(-pi,pi));
h = abs(8 - 2*cos(w1+w2) - 2*cos(w1) - 2*cos(w2) - 2*cos(w1-w2));
surf(w1,w2,h);
title('2D spectrum of filter');
```

`w1` and `w2` provide unique combinations of the frequencies defined horizontally and vertically at each respective spatial location of the arrays.  `w1` and `w2` will in fact be two-dimensional.  For each unique combination of `w1` and `w2`, we determine what the magnitude of the spectra will be.  Once we calculate these, we can put all of this information together in a nice three-dimensional surface plot.

We thus get:

[image]

Take note that both dimensions span from `[-pi,pi]`.  If you examine the spectrum, you will see that the DC component gets nulled to 0, which is actually a high-pass filter, and **not** a sharpening filter.  See my note below.

---

## Minor note

BTW, your 2D filter definition is **not** a 2D sharpening filter.  It is simply a 2D Laplacian, which is an edge detection and thus a high-pass filter.  It only detects edges.  If you want to properly sharpen the image, make sure you add 1 to the **centre** of the kernel, and so what you're really after is:

```
h2 = [-1 -1 -1; -1 9 -1; -1 -1 -1];
```

The offset of 1 will ensure that you are leaving the original signal untouched, but also adding the high-pass results on top of the original signal to thus sharpen your input.

Comment: This is... comprehensive!!

Comment: Wow, I wish I could upvote more than once. Did you write that for this occasion or took it from another such occasion. You could probably easily write a book about such things (and Matlab)!

Comment: @Trilarion thanks :) I actually wrote the equations in LaTeX just for this post. Also, I have not written this stuff about the DFT before. First time! I actually was halfway through writing the post before Luis answered. These equations take a long time to write! Thanks for your sentiments btw :) and your vote!

Answer (score 4):

To plot the frequency response of a 1D FIR filter, use [`freqz`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/freqz.html):

```
h = [-1, 3, -1]; %// FIR impulse response
N = 128; %// number of frequency samples
freqz(h,1,N); %// "1" because the filter is not recursive
```

[image]

The frequency axis is normalized to half the sample frequency, as usual.

See the [documentation of `freqz`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/freqz.html) for further options.

---

To plot the frequency response of a 2D FIR filter, use [`freqz2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/freqz2.html):

```
h = [-1, -1, -1; -1, 8, -1; -1, -1, -1]; %// FIR impulse response (filter mask)
N = 128; %// number of frequency samples
freqz2(h,N,N)
```

[image]

The frequency axes are normalized to half the sample frequency, as in the 1D case.

See the [documentation of `freqz2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/freqz2.html) for further options.

Comment: I was actually writing up my post and LaTeX'ing up all of the equations, and you answered before I could finish lol.  BTW, I've modified my post to give you tribute as `freqz/freqz2` is much easier to use.  Thanks for your compliments with my post :)

Comment: I didn't read the question though, so I didn't see the 1D case was asked about as well. I've added that @rayryeng

Comment: No problem at all :) Nice to see the 1D case.  This almost feels like a Wiki entry.  Part of the post goes into the derivation, and the next part goes into the MATLAB tools.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, haha. But you definitely did the hardest part!